# Form Script to compare response to google sheet data

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets, compare, match

I am not an expert at writing scripts so I need help here.
I would like to write a script that compares the email address entered by a respondent on a form to the data in the column of another google sheet. The data in that column is a collection of email addresses previously captured by an altogether different form.

If there is a match, the respond should skip the next question and go to a different section in the form instead. If there is no match, the respondent should proceed to the very next question.

The idea is to prevent a respondent whose email address is already captured in another google sheet from supplying other information that we already have about them. So, I am using the email address as the determinant for whose data we have partly captured in the past.

Any solutions out there?

Comment: Hi there, Google forms are not THAT dynamic. You can add logic based on select/radio type questions but not based on text entry.

Answer (score 1):

***Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved directly.***

You can *redirect* a user to another section based on the response from a previous one - so you can ask them to (re)input their email and redirect them to the section in question.

If you want to do this programmatically, however, you may have to write your own HTML form and/or try the approach provided already and create two forms for the two user categories.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show/hide Google form sections dynamically, what you can do is create 2 forms:

**Form A** : For unregistered users.

**Form B** : For registered users (email already registered)

Then create a Google web application that request the user's email, search for the email in your database and based on its existence, redirect to **Form A/B.**

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, people